# display data in the drop down menu

Tags: php

I want to fetch data from the database in a form of drop down menu. but as I run the code, the only name that appear in the drop down is the first one in the database. how can I make all the name appear in the drop down?

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $sqladmin = "SELECT * FROM admin";
    $result = mysql_query($sqladmin);

    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $name1 = $row['name1'];
?>
```

.

```
<tr>
    <td>user</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <label>
        <select name="user" id="user">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <?php echo '<option value="'.$row['name1'].'">' . $row['name1'] . '</option>';?>
        </select>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) with a while loop to iterate all the result data

```
<?php
  include('config.php');

  $sqladmin = "SELECT * FROM admin";
  $result = mysql_query($sqladmin);

  if($result === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error());
  }
?>

<tr>
    <td>user</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
          <select name="user" id="user">
          <option selected="selected"></option>
          <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo '<option value="'.$row['name1'].'">' . $row['name1'] . '</option>';
          } ?>
          </select>
      </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over the result...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['name1'].'">' . $row['name1'] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into an array....

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array(
$result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){$name1[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); and write option tag in while loop. For more info refer https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

Change this block alone with following changes :

```
       <select name="user" id="user">
       <option selected="selected"></option>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['name1'].'">' . $row['name1'] . '</option>';
          }?>
       </select>
```